# Magento Site 404 on Front End and Back End

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I tried to export a database from the Magento admin, and during the export I got an error message... upon refreshing the page, both the front-end and back-end of my site shows a 404 error. Site files and database seem to be intact, but can't access anything.

Comment: Did you check 'Put store on the maintenance mode while backup creation' when doing backup?

Comment: I didn't do that. Should I have?

Answer (score 0):

open phpinfo(); in magento site and check that mod_rewrite is loaded. After that change your Web Server Rewrites to No. That will fix it

Comment: Where is phpinfo();? Sorry if that is a very basic question.